# プッシュ通知の受信について

Tags: monaca, push-notification, baas

Monacaとニフティmobile backendを利用しプッシュ通知を送信していますが
特定のデバイスだけなぜかプッシュ通知が受信できません。

調べたところ、原因は「Wifi接続を行っていなかった所為」でした。

該当のデバイスはXperia 4G回線を使用しており
その時はデバイストークンの登録もできませんでした。
ところがWifi接続に変更したところデバイストークンの登録は
できましたし、プッシュ通知の受信も可能です。

また、デバイストークンの登録の時にWifi接続を行い登録確認後
4G回線に戻しプッシュ通知を送信すると、これは受信できませんでした。
そしてまたWifiに戻すと受信できなかったプッシュ通知が一気に来ました。

以上の事から、「4G回線はプッシュ通知を受信できない」
という結論に至ったのですがこれの回避手段がわかりませんので質問した次第です。

この辺りは調べてみても、
「Wifi接続をやめたらプッシュ通知が来る」というケースは見つかっても
「Wifi接続じゃないとプッシュ通知が来ない」というケースは見つかりませんでした・・・

Comment: 4G回線でどのくらいの時間を待って受信できないと判断しましたか？

Comment: おおよそ15分程度です。これ以上かかるようならどの道廃案となりそうです。

Comment: 別の端末ですが、4Gでプッシュ通知を受信するだけのアプリを作って確認してみましたが、時間帯にもよりますが1～3分後に受信しました。もし問題がXperiaと限定されているのであれば、同型の機種を入手して確認するか、モバイル通信の場合はパケット節約のために通信を遮断する設定またはそのようなアプリがインストールされていないかなど確認した方がよろしいかと思います。